# Get the Max Value from 3 columns in excel

Tags: excel-2007

I have a table with three columns of dates and three respective contacts made. From this table i would like to get the max date and contact relevant to that date. My data is as below:

```
DATE1   CONTACT1    DATE2   CONTACT2    DATE3   CONTACT3    MaxDate MaxContact
25/11/2014  Phone   21/03/2014  Visit   21/03/2014  Visit       
30/09/2014  Phone   03/03/2014  Visit   10/10/2014  Visit       
26/11/2014  Phone   18/02/2014  Visit   18/02/2014  Visit       
13/08/2014  phone   14/12/2012  Visit   29/05/2014  Phone
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

In **G2** enter:

```
=MAX(A2,D2,E2)
```

and copy down and in **H2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A2:F2,1,MATCH(G2,A2:E2,0)+1)
```

and copy down to yield:

[image]